# Conditions for a wave in a dispersive medium to have a local wavenumber and frequency

Tags: waves

Suppose that there's a wave travelling in a dispersive medium (it's speed depends on it's frequency, in other words).  Suppose that there's a solution in which each point in space and time we can associate a local wavenumber and local frequency. Writing the local wavenumber and local frequency as two functions (both dependent on space, obviously, and time as well), what are the physical conditions on these functions for such solutions to exist?

Comment: In my opinion this question is not only unphysical but also mathematically contradictory. Even if you have an inhomogeneous dispersive medium, mathematically, you cannot  have solutions of the wave equation with both local frequencies and corresponding wavevectors depending on the location in space.

Comment: @freecharly i found it weird too, but apparently that's a question on a university undergraduate past paper.  I'll quote the exact wording:

"Consider a solution of the dispersive wave system which obeys the dispersion relation derived in (b) such that at each point of space and time one can associate a local wave number k ̄ = k(x, t) and a local angular frequency ω ̄ = ω(x, t). What are the physical conditions that these functions k ̄ and ω ̄ must obey for such a solution to exist?"

Comment: @delickrow123 - It would be helpful if you could give  "the dispersion relation derived in (b)" and also an explanation of how it was derived.

Comment: @freecharly The dispersion relation is "w^2=(ck)^2+a." It was derived from a partial differential equation given in the question: it's mainly the usual wave equation, but a term "a*y(x,t)" added to the side involving the second derivative of time; "a" is just a constant.

Comment: Can you, please, write down  the given partial differential equation. It is not clear whether $y(x,t)$ is the variable of this wave equation to be solved for or whether it is just a given function of time and space?

Comment: @freecharly
The partial differential equation is:
dy/dt-c^2dy/dx+ay=0

sorry both derivatives are partial and second order (I don't know how to type the correct notation here).  y(x,t) is a function to be solved for.

Answer (score 1):

This is the key part of Hamilton's Theory of Rays which leads his ray equations 
$$
\dot {\bf k} = -\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial {\bf x}},\\
\dot {\bf x}= + \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial {\bf k}}.
$$
Here $\omega({\bf k},{\bf x})$ is the local expression they want, $\dot {\bf x}$ is the velocity of the center of the wavepacket, and 
$$
\dot {\bf k} \equiv  \frac{\partial {\bf k}}{\partial t} + (\dot {\bf x}\cdot \nabla) {\bf k}
$$
is the time derivative as you ride along with the wavepacket.

The  requirement for the local form of $\omega$ is that size of the wavepacket and the scale  of the spatial inhomogeneities in the coefficients of the wave equation be much larger than the wavelength. This  ensures  that the geometric optics approximation is valid. See, for example the, discussion and derivation of Hamilton's ray equations in Lighthill's book "Waves in Fluids"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can deduce from this partial differential equation (given in the comment) and the corresponding dispersion relation, which assumes wave solutions $$ ∼\exp i(kz-\omega t)$$ the physical conditions for the validity of these solutions it that both $\omega (x,t)$ and $k(x,t)$ are independent of location and time and thus constants in both x and t.